# node.js - how to switch a database in mongodb driver?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I'm new to this stuff and just stuck in the middle of nowhere. Am using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) and am in need to switch to another database (after authentication against admin db). I googled and found this [topic](http://groups.google.com/group/node-mongodb-native/browse_thread/thread/5b89a7f7b5b27e47) where the creator of library recommends to keep a connection for each db in a hash. So my question is - how do I accomplish it?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121148/changing-mongo-database for an alternative solution

Answer (score 3):

Just create different database connections and store them in an object.

```
var dbConnections = {};

var dbConnections.authDb = new Db('adminDb', server, {});
dbConnections.authDb.authenticate(username, password);

var dbConnections.otherDb = new Db('otherDb', server, {});
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

There's an example hidden in the MongoDB driver docs under [Db](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#db):

```
[...]
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  [...]

  // Reference a different database sharing the same connections
  // for the data transfer
  var secondDb = db.db("integration_tests_2");

  // Fetch the collections
  var multipleColl1 = db.collection("multiple_db_instances");
  var multipleColl2 = secondDb.collection("multiple_db_instances");

  [...]
});
```